# Why doesn't my MVC3 AD authorization filter seem to work when running locally?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, authorization

I'm writing a simple web app using ASP.NET MVC3, and I want to restrict access to this app to members of an Active Directory group in our domain.

I've done this using an authorization filter in the controller, as follows:

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
   [Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAINNAME\MyApp_AccessControlGroup")]
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
      public ActionResult index()
      {
         //action code
      }

      //More actions here
   }
}
```

I have not defined a custom authorization filter, although I did modify web.config to only allow Windows Authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
   <!--<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />-->
</authentication>

<!--Added for Windows authentication-->
<authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

And this works very well when I deploy it to our development webserver (using Visual Studio's Publish feature, if it matters). If I am not in the MyApp_AccessControlGroup group, I am prompted for credentials when I try to bring up the app in a browser. But if I am in the group, then I can see the webpage as expected.

This is not the case when I debug in Visual Studio. When I press F5 and the ASP.NET Development Server starts on my workstation, I can see the site **even when I am not in the AD group.**

Why does this happen? I would expect the authorization filter to still check for group membership, no matter where the code was running.

Comment: Do you have a roleManager section in your web config? If so, can you post it? Also, do you have `<identity impersonate="false" />` in your web config?

Comment: @SteveMallory I have neither of those in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only thing I can think of is that you are running Visual Studio as an Administrator, so the development server is running as an Administrator, thus giving you access to the URL.

Comment: I tried running as another account without administrator rights, and encountered the same behavior. Do I understand correctly that this behavior is not usual?

Comment: The only time I've used windows authentication and authorization is when I rolled my own role provider, which retrieved the roles from a database; so I don't know the answer to that. For debugging this, you might try instantiating the default role provider and call `.GetRolesForUser( username )` on it - see what you get in your dev machine. Here's a link that should help [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.provider.aspx)